# How to add additional model to list and filter on custom condition

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have **4 models** from **4 different tables :**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    player_surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sport_type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
  
class Results_2019(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    first_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    second_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    average_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
       
class Results_2018(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)         
    first_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    second_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    average_score=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)

class Weight(models.Model):
     player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)         
     year2019=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
     year2018=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
```

I use these models to filter based on meeting certain condition. Foreign key does not work for me ( i tried i do not what is wrong).

```
ABC = []
for MyResults in [Results_2019, Results_2018 ]:

     results_list = MyResults.objects.annotate(increase=F('second_score') / 
     F('first_score'),total=F('second_score') + 
     F('first_score',).filter(increase__gt=0.2,total__gt=average_score,)
     ABC.extend(results_list.values_list('player_name', flat=True))
DoubleSNames = list(set([x for x in ABC if ABC.count(x) == 2]))

finallist=list(Profile.objects.filter(player_name__in=DoubleSNames).
values_list('player_name', 'player_surname'))
```

This **code** returns list of players and their surname who meet the criteria.

However i can't embed `Weight class` in list and filter based on

```
 score_weight=first_score/Weight.year19
```

and then filter if `score_weight > 30`

I tried to embed

```
weight_list=[Weight.year19,Weight.year18]
```

How can i use `weight_list` with `MyResults` to calculate `score_weight=first_score/Weight.year19`

How to to do it?

Is that possible at all to do that ?

---

**Additional**:

When i asked you this question i minimised formula i put in filter so after i understand code answered i learn and i can solve independently. Which i did the majority, however i get lost as i haven't done that before but want to learn.

However there are 2 formula I can't insert in the code and make it work. I am keep learning and some are confusing.

Questions:

1. So the code answered to the question in annotate:

   total=F('second_score') + F('first_score')

This is from the code.

Formula I want to embed and filter is:

```
total_growth=total2019/total2018
```

So total of 2019 divided by total of 2018). In Python there is the list I tried to apply like:

```
total_growth=list(map(lambda i,w: (i/w) if w else 0, total[0],total[1]))
```

And check on condition whether `total_growth > 0.05`

However it does not work and i do not exactly where to put it in the code  to make it work?

2. How to filter by `sport_type (class Profile)` so **sport_type** is not in football.

Would appreciate help to my additional queries to close finally my concern over this question.

Comment: 1000 digits?  Get real.

Comment: Will this data go into a database?  Or should [MySQL] be removed from tags?

Comment: It is static data from database so names of models are actual table names

Comment: To debug this, can you log the calculated `score_weight`, or include it in the output instead of using it in the `if` statement, or manually calculate it for some of the players for which you believe it should be more than 30?

Comment: As a side-note, a couple of points that could be big speed-ups: (a) do the filtering on the database side, with more complex `.filter()` clauses and [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters), rather than in an `if` statement; and (b) use `Profile.objects.filter(player_name__in=DoubleSNames)` rather than calling `Profile.objects.filter(player_name=name)[0]` in a loop. Whether these are worthwhile depends on how much data you have and whether current performance is satisfactory...

Comment: could please share your answer and code in an answer -  this is bounty question

Comment: also the code you shared does not work. My question is about my concern how to embede complex filter with list values. If you knwo how please share code. I tried many times i get error that Profile only has columns : player_name , player_surname, sport_type .

Comment: The fix by @sabik is correct and very useful. Your problem was that also the following line must be modified or all five lines can be combined to one command. (I share it in my answer because it is long)

Comment: Question: Is the `player_name` unique in every table so that no two rows with the same player_name can exist in the same table for no player? If I understand, your tables Result_* and Weight are not live data that are added continuously, but a summary for the year or a summary of weight for the player.

Comment: Yes you are right : player_name  is unique in every table. Yes you are correct  Result_* and Weight are static data and represents a summary of results for year for each player.

Comment: @Günel - My answer was mostly to log or output or otherwise obtain the calculated `score_weight`, to make sure that it is, indeed, more than 30 for the relevant records. This will rule out the possibility that the code is working as written, but the data doesn't in fact contain any records with `score_weight > 30` — whether because there are none, or because of some mismatch between the data and the calculation (for instance, maybe it should be 0.30 rather than 30).

Comment: @sabik in fact it depends on scores and weights, if the maximum score is 100 and the weight around 80, then it will be at the maximum equal to 1.25, but if scores are >1000 ....

Comment: @Houda - Yes, that's why my suggestion is to print them out and see what the actual numbers are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Possible bugs:

Maybe you forgot to initialize some variables in the loop for Weight. (your intention was not clear to me)

Other possible problem could be combined tabs and spaces. The code is incorrectly indented after you have pasted it to Stackoverflow. Maybe your editor has a different tab size, maybe Python2 interpreted it as valid, but not how you see it in the editor. Try to run python with `-t` option, to see warnings if the interpreted logic depends on the tab size. The recommended code style for Python is to not use TABs and to fix all indents to multiples of 4 spaces. The best editor setting for Python is to automatically expand all tabs to spaces.

---

B) optimizations:

very important

`finallist` simplified from many database requests to one request:

```
finallist = list(
    Profile.objects.filter(player_name__in=DoubleSNames)
    .values_list('player_name', 'player_surname')
)
```

less important optimization

simplify `MyResults.objects.all()` to a request with less data rows

```
results_list = MyResults.objects.filter(
    averrage__gt=50,
    second_score__gt=70 - F(first_score),
    average__lt=F(first_score) + F(second_score),
    first_score__gt=0,
    second_score__gt=0.2 * F(first_score),
)
ABC.extend(results_list.values_list('player_name', flat=True))
```

It shouldn't be done before the view will be slow, because readability counts and maybe this will be not the bottle neck.
Disadvantages:
The expression for `increase` with `Case()` `When()` functions would be bad readable. Everything is reformulated, but it is still less readable than a filter on plain Python list.

---

**EDIT**:
I accept that you forgot to set the primary key and foreign keys that suggested @Houda, how is normal in Django and that it can be too late to allow Django to add indexes to these tables.

If all data from `Profile` and `Weight` can fit in the memory then you can easily map it by a dictionary, otherwise you can filter it by individual names as you did originally or to load them to the memory by a subset of players.

```py
from collections import Counter

profile_map = {x.player_name: x for x in Player.objects.all()}
weight_map = {x.player_name: x for x in Weight.objects.all()}
totals_map = {}  # like rows: player, columns: year
ABC = []
for MyResults in [[Results_2019, Results_2018 ]:
    results_list = (
        MyResults.objects
        .annotate(
            increase=F('second_score') / F('first_score'),
            total=F('second_score') + F('first_score')
        )
       .filter(
            increase__gt=0.2,
            total__gt=average_score,
            # ... possible more filters
        )
    )
    year_str = MyResults._meta.model_name[-4:]
    for result in results_list:
        player_name = result.player_name
        player = profile_map[player_name]
        weight = weight_map[player_name]
        weight_year = vars(weight)['year' + year_str[-2:]]
        score_weight = result.first_score / weight_year
        totals_map.setdefault(player_name, {})[year_str] = result.total
        if score_weight > 30 and player.sport_type not in ['football']:
            ABC.append(player_name)
counter = Counter(ABC)
DoubleSNames = {name for name, count in counter.items() if count == 2}

finallist = []
for player_name in DoubleSNames:
    totals = totals_map['player_name']
    total2018 = totals.get('2018', 0)
    total2019 = totals.get('2019', 0)
    if totals2018 > 0 and total2019 / total2018 > 0.05:
        player = player_map[player_name]
        finallist.append([player.player_name, player.player_surname])
```

(It is not an advanced question about django-queryset now, but how to simulate a database relation by Python.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your imcode optimization advice is very helpful.  Howeverl my question is about how i can use values form class Weight  in calculations with other values from other models. Table Weight is seperate table in DB and contains the exact values that i listed in this model. I have updated my question where i followed your advice, however still in this code i do not how to embed Weight class values calculate with other values and filter if values is more than 30. Would appreciate if you could help to understand how to do it and overall is it possible to do that?

Comment: The question is actually mix of models-quaryset and table relation as my models does not accept Foreign key i do not know here i did wrong so I decided to use Python code to get the desired result. I accpted your answer as it did answer the most of my questions that haven't even asked including your optimization advice.

Though i have 2 issues left in my mind that i am conccerned and i would appreciate if you could help to understand. If you do not mind to help could you please see my updated question in Additional section i listed 2 issues for this question that arose.

Comment: I accepted these two last questions and and edited only the code without any comment. You will deal with a problem if one player is competing in two sports :-) but it would be a problem of data, not a problem of code

Comment: The example eliminates only the exact field "football". The code is correct. You can debug the problem by filtering only one problematic person name temporarily and print some internal variables. Maybe there is a white space at the end of sport name. It can be interesting what was the problem, but I will not answer more.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own code, you are right the result is always empty because of this conditions:

```
total=second+first
score_weight=total/weight19
if increase > 0.2 and  total > average and average > 50 and total > 70 and 
score_weight > 30 : ABC.append(result.player_name)
```

score_weight will never be > 30

you can find below my code, when I put score_weight > 1 I can get results:

model.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     player_surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     sport_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Results2019(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    second_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    average_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)


class Results2018(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    second_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    average_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)


class Weight(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year19 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    year18 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
```

views.py

```
def myPageView():
    ABC = {}
    players = Profile.objects.all().values()

    for result in players:
        for data in [[Results2019, 'year19'], [Results2018, 'year18']]:
            Results = data[0].objects.get(player_name__exact=result['player_name'])
            if Results:
                wgt = Weight.objects.filter(player_name__exact=result['player_name']).values(data[1]).last()
                if wgt:
                    if float(Results.first_score) > 0.0:
                        increase19 = float(Results.second_score) / float(Results.first_score)
                    else:
                        increase19 = 0
                    total = float(Results.second_score) + float(Results.first_score)
                    score_weight = total / float(wgt[data[1]])
                    if (increase19 > 0.2) and (total > float(Results.average_score)) and \
                            (float(Results.average_score) > 50) and (total > 70) and (score_weight > 1):
                        ABC[result['player_name']] = result['player_surname']
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
    print('*************ABC***************', ABC)
    finallist = []
    for name in ABC.keys():
        finallist.append([name, ABC[name]])
    print('*************finallist***************', finallist)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but forign key does not work in my case that is way to commited list way to be able to filter form different tables.

Comment: the pb is not in your code bu in coditions you've made: score_weight > 30 is not possible  I think,

Comment: you do not have to use forign key. it's optional

Comment: Could you please see my updated question , I changed the code improved it so it is  more efficient. Please see if you could embed weight class columns in the code so i can calculate and filter based on 3 models

Answer (score 0):

model.py

```
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    player_surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sport_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Results2019(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    second_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    average_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    increase = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False, editable=False)
    total = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.second_score / self.first_score > 0.2:
            self.increase = 1
        else:
            self.increase = 0
        if self.second_score + self.first_score > self.average_score:
            self.total = 1
        else:
            self.total = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Results2018(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    first_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    second_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    average_score = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    increase = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False, editable=False)
    total = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.second_score / self.first_score > 0.2:
            self.increase = 1
        else:
            self.increase = 0
        if self.second_score + self.first_score > self.average_score:
            self.total = 1
        else:
            self.total = 0
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Weight(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    year19 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
    year18 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, null=True, blank=True,)
```

views.py

```
ABC = {}
weight_dict = defaultdict(dict)
player_dict = {}

for player in Profile.objects.values('player_name', 'player_surname'):
    player_dict[player['player_name']] = player['player_surname']

for wt in Weight.objects.values():
    weight_dict[wt['player_name']] = {'year19': wt['year19'], 'year18': wt['year18']}

for MyResults in [[Results2019, 'year19'], [Results2018, 'year18']]:
    results_list = MyResults[0].objects.\
        filter(increase__exact=True, total__exact=True).values('player_name', 'first_score')

    for t in results_list:
        if t['player_name'] in ABC.keys():
            pass
        elif float(t['first_score']) / float(weight_dict[t['player_name']][MyResults[1]]) > 30:
            ABC[t['player_name']] = player_dict[t['player_name']]

finallist = ABC.items()
```